# Can someone help me find where my brackets/parenthesis are wrong?

Tags: java

I'm writing a chatbot for my APCS course. I'm getting an error, error: class, interface or enum expected, which I've found out is typically triggered when parenthesis or brackets don't match up properly. I have minor dyslexia, which makes trying to find these hell. If someone would help me, I would be greatly thankful. Here's the code.
    public class Magpie2
{

```
public String getGreeting();
{
    return "Hello, let's talk.";
}

/**
 * Gives a response to a user statement
 * 
 * @param statement
 *            the user statement
 * @return a response based on the rules given
 */
public String getResponse(String statement)
{
     String response = "";
if (statement.length() == 0);
{
  response = "Say something, please.";
}
    String response = "";
    if (statement.indexOf(" no ") >= 0)
    {
        response = "Why so negative?";
    }
    else if (statement.indexOf("mother") >= 0
            || statement.indexOf("father") >= 0
            || statement.indexOf("sister") >= 0 )
    {
        response = "Tell me more about your family.";
    }
    else if (statement.indexOf("brother") >= 0 )
    {
        response = "I have a brother too!";
      }
    else if (statement.indexOf("cat") >= 0
            || (statement.indexOf("rabbit") >= 0) ) 
    {
     response = "Tell me more about your pets.";
     }
     else if (statement.indexOf("dog") >= 0 )
     {
         response = "I wish I had a dog.";
        }
     else if (statement.indexOf("Mrs") >= 0
            || statement.indexOf("Ms") >= 0
            || statement.indexOf("Fisher") >= 0
            || statement.indexOf("Zaengle") >= 0 )
            {
        response = "They sound like a good teacher";
    }
    else if (statement.indexOf("Mr") >= 0 )
    {
        response = "Most of my teachers are mr's";
      }
    else
    {
        response = getRandomResponse();
    }
    return response;
}
```

}

```
private String getRandomResponse()
{
    final int NUMBER_OF_RESPONSES = 6;
    double r = Math.random();
    int whichResponse = (int)(r * NUMBER_OF_RESPONSES);
    String response = "";

    if (whichResponse == 0)
    {
        response = "Interesting, tell me more.";
    }
    else if (whichResponse == 1)
    {
        response = "Hmmm.";
    }
    else if (whichResponse == 2)
    {
        response = "Do you really think so?";
    }
    else if (whichResponse == 3)
    {
        response = "You don't say.";
    }
    else if (whichResponse == 4)
    {
        response = "Ah.";
    }
    else if (whichResponse == 5)
    {
        response = "Yeah.";
    }

    return response;
}
```

}
}

Comment: Forgot to say, the error is triggered in the line private String getRandomResponse()

Comment: What text editor/IDE do you use? A decent one will show matching parenthesis/brackets.

Comment: Asking on StackOverflow to find your mismatching brackets is hardly a sustainable approach to programming. If you use an IDE (which you should), you can format the code. Doing so will tell you where the indentation suddenly seems off -- that's where you're missing something.

Comment: In addition to the excess brackets, `public String getGreeting();` and `if (statement.length() == 0);` both shouldn't have the semicolon on the end.

Comment: @StephaneM I use BlueJ, which my course teacher makes us use. It kind of shows matching things, but at the same time it misses a few.

Comment: @resueman Thanks, but the problem is I can't find the excess brackets (unless you mean the two at the very end, that was just me seeing if that would fix the error)

Comment: I never tried BlueJ but That would be surprising if an IDE  _designed for beginners_ (as it states) doesn't highlight missing block termination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have more than 1 mistake:

1. remvoe the `;` at the end of the method `getGreeting()`
2. in the method `getResponse()` the variable `String response` is declared twice! Remove one of the declarations
3. At the end of the `getResponse()` method you do have one curly brace too much!
4. At the very end of the program you do have one curly brace too much!

---

Not a syntax error, but probably a semantical error:

```
if (statement.length() == 0);
{
    response = "Say something, please.";
}
```

Take a close look at the semicolon (`;`) after the `if`! This semicolon displays an empty statement and the block `{ response = ... }` will always be executed, not only when the condition of the `if` is true

---

Those mistakes were easy to find for me since i use a proper IDE which tells me where my syntax-errors are!

You should probably think about using an IDE like Eclipse or any other!

Comment: Oh my gosh, thanks! You're a lifesaver, will accept when the timer is done.